# can't grab PHP $_POST variable

Tags: php, page-template

We're using a custom thank you page that is designed to display a custom brochure PDF depending on what landing page sent you to the thank you page.

On the landing page, we're using a Gravity Form which has a redirect query string of `house={embed_post:ID}`:
[image]

This is working fine. For example, from one landing page, submitting the form takes us to http://www.rossnorthhomes.com.au/thank-you/?house=3466

The thank you page template is:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Thank You Page (Custom Template)
 */
$house = $_POST['house'];

$page_sidebar = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'fave_page_sidebar', true );
$page_background = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'fave_page_background', true );

if( $page_sidebar == 'none' ) {
    $content_area = 'col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12';
} else if( $page_sidebar == 'left_sidebar' ) {

    $content_area = 'col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 list-grid-area container-contentbar';

} else if( $page_sidebar == 'right_sidebar' ) {
    $content_area = 'col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 container-contentbar';
}

if( $page_background == 'none' && $page_sidebar == 'none' ) {
    $page_bg = 'no-padding-bg';
}
$sticky_sidebar = houzez_option('sticky_sidebar');
$sidebar_meta = houzez_get_sidebar_meta($post->ID);
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/page', 'title' ); ?>

    <section class="section-detail-content houzez-page-template">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="<?php echo esc_attr( $content_area ); ?>">
                <div class="page-main">
                    <div class="white-block <?php echo esc_attr( $page_bg ); ?>">
                        <?php
                        // Start the loop.
                        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                            // Include the page content template.
                            get_template_part( 'content', 'page' );

                            // End the loop.
                        endwhile;
                        ?>
                        <?php
                        switch ($house) {
                            case 429: /* The Katherine */
                                echo "<p>Download <a href='http://www.rossnorthhomes.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/The-Katherine-Display.pdf'>property brochure</a>.</p>";
                                break;
                            case 3466: /* The Beaufort */
                                echo "<p>Download <a href='http://www.rossnorthhomes.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/The-Beaufort-Display.pdf'>property brochure</a>.</p>";
                                break;
                            case 3481: /* The Merivale */
                                echo "<p>Download <a href='http://www.rossnorthhomes.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/The-Merivale-Display.pdf'>property brochure</a>.</p>";
                                break;
                        }?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <?php if( $page_sidebar != 'none' ) { ?>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 container-sidebar <?php if( $sticky_sidebar['page_sidebar'] != 0 ){ echo 'houzez_sticky'; }?>">
                <aside id="sidebar" class="sidebar-white">
                    <?php
                    if( $sidebar_meta['specific_sidebar'] == 'yes' ) {
                        if( is_active_sidebar( $sidebar_meta['selected_sidebar'] ) ) {
                            dynamic_sidebar( $sidebar_meta['selected_sidebar'] );
                        }
                    } else {
                        if( is_active_sidebar( 'page-sidebar' ) ) {
                            dynamic_sidebar( 'page-sidebar' );
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                </aside>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>

        </div>

    </section>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Note:

```
$house = $_POST['house'];
```

&

```
<?php
    switch ($house) {
        case 3466: /* The Beaufort */
            echo "<p>Download <a href='http://www.rossnorthhomes.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/The-Beaufort-Display.pdf'>property brochure</a>.</p>";
```

Can you see why the custom content is not being injected? i.e:

```
<p>Download <a href='http://www.rossnorthhomes.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/The-Beaufort-Display.pdf'>property brochure</a>.</p>
```

Comment: Did you try: $house = $_GET['house'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced

```
$house = $_POST['house'];
```

with

```
$house = isset( $_GET['house'] ) ? $_GET['house'] : false;
```

and it's working now.